# can not config react routes

Tags: reactjs, routes

can you help me, i have next routes

```
export const routes = (
  <div>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path='home' component={Home} />
      <Route path='categories' component={Category} />
      <Route path='books' component={Book}>
        <Route path='/categories/:category_id/books' component={Book} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
  </div>
)
```

when  i go to '/categories/:category_id/books' path than it displays "books" tab with books by category but when i click on link '/books' then it still displays old content and component "Book" not reloaded. It should display all books without category. books loads in

```
class Book

componentDidMount() {
    const { category_id } = this.props.params;

    category_id ? this.props.loadBooksByCategory(category_id) : this.props.loadBooks();
  }
```

Comment: I dont think the DidMount function is called here, because you never went out of 'books' context. Maybe you can use the componentWillReceiveProps event instead of the componentDidMount (beware that first load does not trigger willreceiveprops)

Comment: Since both routes use the same component, you should have a trigger mechanism in order to re-render the component. To do so, you can make use of the states. You can define your list as component's state, so when you apply or remove filters, the state will be updated which triggers component to re-renders.